# Django website on VPS with WHM CPanel

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, vps, mod-python

What's the difference between mod_wsgi and mod_python.

In order to publish django websites on VPS, which one should I install on VPS?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mod_wsgi`.  `mod_python` is the old and direct interface to Apache from Python. `wsgi` is a standard interface between any webserver and Python (`mod_wsgi` is the Apache implementation).

Comment: I tried yum install mod_wsgi. but it gave me error that httpd is conflicting with ea4. I couldn't install. But I've installed via pip. Is it gonna work?

Comment: Installation issues with your system's package manager, and conflicts between installed packages, sound like a new questions (you should ask this as a new question, potentially on ServerFault).

Comment: You cannot use yum installed mod_wsgi with a Apache distro other than system Apache provided by the operating system. You would need to install mod_wsgi yourself from source code compiled against the Apache you want to use if different to system Apache.

Comment: The main reason I'm asking this question is to get answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154689/setup-python-app-module-missing-on-cpanel-vps

Comment: The question you link to is way too broad - and has absolutely nothing to do with the question you've asked here.  There are tons of tutorials on setting up Django on various systems. @GrahamDumpleton gave you the answer on pip vs. yum installs (smart people generally listen to Graham when he speaks about mod_wsgi <wink>).